# Adding GPS information to my current Project

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie here.I am trying to create an APP that will scan all the Wi-Fi channels and put it in a file. Now i wanted to integrate GPS information of the device for each particular scan and put it in the same file. Currently i am broadcasting the Wi-Fi information and using a Broadcast filter to capture it. What would be the correct approach to add the GPS tracking information to my current application.

This is my DataPoint Code

```
public class DataPoint {
int     level;
String  BSSID;
String  SSID;
long    time;


public DataPoint(long time, int level, String BSSID, String SSID){
    this.level = level;
    this.time = time;
    this.BSSID = BSSID;
    this.SSID = SSID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("TIME: ").append(time).append("\n");
    sb.append("SSID: ").append(SSID).append("\n");
    sb.append("BSSID: ").append(BSSID).append("\n");
    sb.append("RSSI: ").append(level).append(" [dBm]\n\n");

    return sb.toString();
}

public String toCSVString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(time).append(",");
    sb.append(SSID).append(",");
    sb.append(BSSID).append(",");
    sb.append(level).append("\n");

    return sb.toString();   
}
}
```

This is my MainActivity Code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "RSSIMiner";
WifiManager wifi;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

TextView textStatus;
Button scanButton;
Button recordButton;

boolean toFile = true;
String fid = "0";

Timer tim;
boolean scanning = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setup UI
    textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

    // Set up buttons and listeners
    scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
    recordButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Setup WiFi
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Setup Timer
    tim = new Timer(true);

    // Register Broadcast Receiver
    if (receiver == null)
        receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy()");
    this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    // Scan button
    if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonScan) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick() Scan");

        if(scanning) {
            tim.cancel();
            scanButton.setText(R.string.scan_button);
        } else {
            tim.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    wifi.startScan();
                }
            }, 0, 2000);

            scanButton.setText(R.string.scan_button_scanning);
        }
        scanning = !scanning;

        // Record button
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonRecord) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick() Record");
        toFile = !toFile; 

        if(toFile) {
            Date d = new Date();
            fid = "data-" + d.getTime() + ".csv";
            recordButton.setText(R.string.record_button_recording);
            textStatus.setText("");
        } else {
            recordButton.setText(R.string.record_button);
            Toast.makeText(this, "File saved to " + fid,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Clear button
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonClear) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick() Clear");
        textStatus.setText("");
    }
}

public void update(String s) {
    // Get WiFi status
    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    textStatus.append("\nCurrent WiFi connection: " + info.toString() + "\n\n");
    textStatus.append(s);
    textStatus.append("-------------------------------");

    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView);
    sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    Log.d(TAG, "UI updated.");
}
}
```

Finally my Broadcast Receiver Code

```
package se.illuminati.rssiminer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

  public class WiFiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "WiFiScanReceiver";
MainActivity rssiminer;

public WiFiScanReceiver(MainActivity rssiminer) {
    super();
    this.rssiminer = rssiminer;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

    List<ScanResult> results = rssiminer.wifi.getScanResults();
    Date d = new Date();


    ArrayList<DataPoint> data = new ArrayList<DataPoint>(results.size());
    for (ScanResult result : results) {
        data.add(new DataPoint(d.getTime(), result.level, result.BSSID, result.SSID));
    }

    String message = String.format("%s networks found. Updating list.",
            results.size());
    Toast.makeText(rssiminer, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() message: " + message);

    StringBuilder sbs = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbm = new StringBuilder();

    for(DataPoint dp : data) {
        sbs.append(dp.toString());
        sbm.append(dp.toCSVString());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Updating UI...");
    rssiminer.update(sbs.toString());

    if(rssiminer.toFile) {              
        try {
            File dataDir = new File("/sdcard/RSSIMiner/");
            dataDir.mkdirs();
            File dataFile = new File(dataDir,rssiminer.fid);
            Log.d(TAG,"Printing to file /sdcard/RSSIMiner/" + rssiminer.fid);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dataFile,true);

            fw.write(sbm.toString());
            fw.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: FileNotFoundException\n" + e.getStackTrace());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: IOException\n" + e.getStackTrace());
            System.exit(1);
        } 


    }

}
}
```

Comment: wth u doing coding for the illuminati

Comment: I think he's missing a fnord statement.

Comment: One of the answers explains how to get the GPS information for a specific provider (e.g. a Wifi provider).  You should use that approach.